# Central error handling on Jersey JAX-RS

Tags: filter, jersey, jax-ws, jax-rs, interceptor

I am doing jaxrs with jersey. I am experience with cxf but not so much with Jersey. Is there a way to set an out-interceptor equivalent to handle exception throws by the resource methods in Jersey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you play with Jersey 2.x, you can use `ExceptionMapper` to handle all exceptions (or particular one) produced by resource methods.

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<java.lang.Exception> {
    public Response toResponse(java.lang.Exception ex) {
        return Response.status(500)
            .entity(ex.getMessage())
            .type("text/plain")
            .build();
    }
}
```